# Code first Entity Framework model in PHP

Tags: php, entity-framework, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

I am recently working in a ASP.Net MVC project where we use code first technique to create all the database table. I really liked the idea, where you don't need to touch the database and create the model classes which are automatically mapped to the database by the EF layer.

I am planning to start a hobby project with PHP and was playing with Laravel (I am newbie in PHP). I was wondering if there is any equivalent framework in PHP that support code first pattern as EF 4.1?

I was looking into some Laravel tutorial, it looks like the ORM (eloquent) doesn't work exactly same way as the EF 4.1 in .net does. I seems to me that you still need to create the table in the database and then you create a model to map the database. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For PHP i suggest looking at Doctrine 2 as ORM. You define your Entities and doctrine will generate the classes and database structure for you.

Comment: Can I easily replace eloquent from laravel with doctrine 2? Or it will be a huge pain? :-)

Comment: As far as i understood, laravel can use Doctrine 2, so it does not seem to be a replacement http://www.laraveldoctrine.org is an implementation of that.

Comment: Awesome! That's a great news!

Answer (score 2):

You may also look into [ReadBeanPHP](http://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php) if you are going to write PHP from scratch. Not very feature-rich or beautiful, but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with EF, but I think what you're referring to is how [Doctrine entity mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html) works. 
Doctrine is a standalone ORM and DBAL, but is the recommended ORM for Symfony. 
Laravel uses some Symfony components.
In [Laravel you write migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations) that you can then run to set up your DB.